# Simple MySQL 5.7 only_full_group_by count

Tags: sql, count, mysql-5.7

I read http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

and http://rpbouman.blogspot.nl/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html

but still getting errors trying to rewrite a simple MySQL query...

TABLE: Event_Visitors

```
Event_ID       |     User_ID     |user_level |rsvp_status | updated_time
foreign int(11)| foreign int(11) | int(3)    |  int(3)    | timestamp (onupdate)
```

This is my table with two foreign keys.
Now i want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT min(ev.Event_ID), ev.User_ID, ev.rsvp_status, ev.updated_time, count(*) 
FROM EVENT_VISITORS ev
GROUP BY ev.User_ID
ORDER BY ev.updated_time DESC
```

And getting the error:

> contains nonaggregated column 'markusp.ev.updated_time' which is not functionally dependent

I know adding ev-updated_time to the group by clause fixes the problem. But i want to count the rows and not show every single row of a user. (count all events a user is attending).

> Adding min(ev.Event_ID) or any_value(ev.Event_ID) doesnt fix the problem.

I dont get it. I mean updated time is dependent on ***User_ID + Event_ID*** so if i add ***User_ID*** to group by and ***MIN(Event_ID)***  should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write the query you want?  That is, be specific about the columns that are aggregated and not aggregated, by putting all non-aggregated columns in the `group by`.  One method is:

```
SELECT min(ev.Event_ID), ev.User_ID, ev.rsvp_status, ev.updated_time, 
       count(*) 
FROM EVENT_VISITORS ev
GROUP BY ev.User_ID, ev.rsvp_status, ev.updated_time
ORDER BY ev.updated_time DESC;
```

Or perhaps you intend this:

```
SELECT min(ev.Event_ID), ev.User_ID,  count(*) 
FROM EVENT_VISITORS ev
GROUP BY ev.User_ID
ORDER BY MAX(ev.updated_time) DESC;
```

Comment: If i putt all non-aggregated columns in the group_by, it will not be "grouped" by 'only' the User_ID. In your query above i will get a count on every user which is grouped on rsvp and updated time. What i want is somewhat all events a user is attending like (distinct user_id) and count the rows.

Comment: P.S. The second query fails cause of MAX(ev.updated_time) in the order by clause.

Comment: @Markus . . . The second query should work precisely because of the `MAX()` in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Mhh my sql doesnt like the query:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY MAX(ev.updated_time) DESC'  in row 4.

However i know where the problem is, ordering by updated_time, while it is not in GROUP_BY like you said. Removing it is working. But it is not ordered by MAX(updated_time)...

Comment: Your query worked like a charm. There is just the comma mistake after the GROUP BY clause.
Thanks a lot :)